# Uploading an image to Google Lens using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to upload images using Selenium on Google lens using this link: https://lens.google.com/search?p=0

By examining the site, I've concluded that If I have copied an image I can paste it on Google lens with Ctrl+V and it automatically uploads. I tried to mimic the exact thing by trying to paste the image from my clipboard. This code does store the image on my clipboard and when I stop the execution and paste it on the browser, it uploads perfectly. However, the program is not able to do so. Code is below:

```
import os
import win32clipboard as clp    
file_path = 'capture.png'

clp.OpenClipboard()
clp.EmptyClipboard()


wide_path = os.path.abspath(file_path).encode('utf-16-le') + b'\0'
clp.SetClipboardData(clp.RegisterClipboardFormat('FileNameW'), wide_path)
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#yDmH0d > div:nth-child(16) > div > ul'))).click()
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL,'v')
```

The second approach I tried to use was to find the input element and send file name as a key, but that too didn't work. One thing I noticed was the input element is not visible at first until you click the Upload Button and then the Computer. So I tried to mimic that as well, still not working. Code is below:

```
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="gb"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/span/div[1]/button'))).click()
time.sleep(1)
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="yDmH0d"]/div[13]/div/ul/li[1]')))
time.sleep(1)
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="gb"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/input'))).send_keys('capture.png')
```

Any idea how to make this work or better approach to upload images?

Answer (score 0):

**This is all you need :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
elem = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html')
ac = ActionChains(driver)
ac.move_to_element(elem).move_by_offset(100, 100).click().perform()
```

**Use this for active the page.
Good luck !**